# Can't save Excel VBA as xla

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have my VBA code ready to have others test, and i was going to give it to them as an Add-in (.xla). I had tested this with some other code, to make sure i could do it, and was able to create an .xla file.

Now, for my current code i cannot create an .xla file. The option does not show up in the SaveAs dialog. I am using Excel 2007. Is there something i'm missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

thanks,

Russ

Comment: If you are using Excel 2007, you should probably be using .xlam instead of the older .xla.

Comment: I'd be willing to try that, which format name is that? Is that in the SaveAs dialog? How was i able to save the previous code as an .xla?

Comment: You probably should be using XLAM extension. Both XLAM and XLA are available in Excel 2010. I don't have a version of 2007 to test, but I'd be surprised if both options are not available in 2007 -- can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Ok, found the answer. When i was trying to saveas an xla, i had the chart tab open. When i went to the worksheet tab, Add-in then became the option.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer! I was trying to solve your problem and hit the same issue !

Comment: Make sure you do not try to save from the VB editor, and that you have an empty document loaded in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer the question. I had had a chart sheet open when i tried to do the SaveAs to an Add-In (.xla) file type. When the Chart Sheet tab was open, Add-in was not an option for the SaveAs. When i went to the worksheet tab, Add-In appeared again, as an option. fyi,

Russ

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

- Start with a blank document and type/import your code

[image: Developer]

- Select Save as Other Formats

[image: Office Orb]

- Pick Excel Add-in, or Excel 97-2003 Addin from the list (way down).

[image: Save As]